# weird icons beside my java project classes

Tags: java, netbeans

I have opened my project today and I noticed some weird icons beside my classes as in this image :

[image]

I don't know what that means !

when I run my application it works great, and I get no exception.

how can I resolve this issue

Comment: Is this the same problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426365/cant-edit-jframe-form-after-netbeansupdate

Comment: Please consider an up vote if you found my input to the point and helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a Source Code repository like SVN or CVS (you might have `checked out` this project out of some code repository) your recent changes must have made your local workspace go out of sync.

By using different colour codes and icons, Netbeans is simply trying to inform you which of these files are in conflict with the repository and need to be merged.

Some of the other icons could simply be informative like that "play" sign on your `.java` files indicates that the file contains a `main()` method and can be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be scared at all, the `IDE` marks the different file types with different icons. Most of the `IDE`s have similar functionality.

Comment: but, before I hadn't this mark, my project also is colored with red and is marked with a little yellow triangle

Comment: What is the drawback you are facing having these icons with your files.

Comment: Yes, it means you are missing some dependencies if it's marked as yellow icon (warning icon)